# Entry based on RSI Signal is delayed but plotted correctly

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My problem is that my RSI indicator shows perfect signals (the lines) which I want to execute with strategy.entry right at the end of the line but the entry is so delayed it ruins every trade. The buy and sell plotshapes are adjusted with offset but even without offset the entry is after.

Is it possible to get the strategy.entry on the RSI indicators end of line? That would be the perfect entry for every trade. Somehow the same conditions for the entry trigger 3-4 candles after the RSI indicator shows.

[image: delayed entry]

Here is the code including the offset. If there is a solution please fix.

```
RSI_PER = 14
pivot_right = 3
pivot_left = 3
max_range=30
min_range=3

rsi_value = ta.rsi(close, RSI_PER)
rsi_valueH = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '60', rsi_value)

plot(rsi_value, title="RSI", linewidth=2, color=color.rgb(255, 255, 255))
hline(50,  linestyle=hline.style_dotted)
rsi_ob = hline(70, linestyle=hline.style_dotted)
rsi_os = hline(30, linestyle=hline.style_dotted)
fill(rsi_ob, rsi_os, color=color.rgb(223, 64, 251, 80))

//check if we have pivot low in rsi
pivot_low_true = na(ta.pivotlow(rsi_value, pivot_left, pivot_right)) ? false : true //returns price of the pivot low point. It returns 'NaN', if there was no pivot low point.

//Create a function that returns true/false
confirm_range(x) =>
    bars = ta.barssince(x == true) //Counts the number of bars since the last time the condition was true
    min_range <= bars and bars <= max_range // makes sure bars is less than 60 and less than 5 and returns true

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// RSI higher low check

RSI_HL_check1 = rsi_value[pivot_right] > ta.valuewhen(pivot_low_true, rsi_value[pivot_right], 1) and confirm_range(pivot_low_true[1])

// Price Lower Low check

price_ll_check1 = low[pivot_right] < ta.valuewhen(pivot_low_true, low[pivot_right], 1)

bullCond =  price_ll_check1 and RSI_HL_check1 and pivot_low_true

//Plot the areas, terneary conditional operator
plot( pivot_low_true ? rsi_value[pivot_right] : na, offset=-pivot_right, linewidth=3, color=(bullCond ? color.green : color.new(color.white, 100))//colornew applies the specified transparency to the given color
     )

plotshape(
     bullCond ? rsi_value[pivot_right] : na,
     offset=-pivot_right,
     text=" BUY ",
     style=shape.labelup,
     location=location.absolute,
     color=color.green,
     textcolor=color.white
     
     )

// RSI lower high check

RSI_HL_check2 = rsi_value[pivot_right] < ta.valuewhen(pivot_low_true, rsi_value[pivot_right], 1) and confirm_range(pivot_low_true[1])

// Price Higher High check

price_ll_check2 = low[pivot_right] > ta.valuewhen(pivot_low_true, low[pivot_right], 1)

bearCond =  price_ll_check2 and RSI_HL_check2 and pivot_low_true

//Plot the areas, terneary conditional operator
plot( pivot_low_true ? rsi_value[pivot_right] : na, offset=-pivot_right, linewidth=3, color=(bearCond ? color.red : color.new(color.white, 100))//colornew applies the specified transparency to the given color
     )

plotshape(
     bearCond ? rsi_value[pivot_right] : na,
     offset=-pivot_right,
     text=" SELL ",
     style=shape.labeldown,
     location=location.absolute,
     color=color.red,
     textcolor=color.white
     
     )

ENTRIES:
strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long, when = bullCond)
strategy.entry("SELL", strategy.short, when = bearCond)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done and not realistic. Those buy and sell labels are drawn with an offset. This indicator needs to wait some bars to confirm the price action. It identifies a significant price move that happened some bars ago and plots the buy/sell signal there.

You cannot do that in real life. You cannot wait 10 days and see the price has moved 10% compared to 10 days ago and then go back 10 days in time and enter a trade.

You cannot execute orders with an offest in pinescript because that doesn't make any sesnse.

Comment: I know that it is not possible to go back in time.. but the indicator detects the signals on time as you can see on the lines.

Comment: I need the entry to be right on time.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to enter? Is it when the indicator gives "BUY" signal?

Comment: At the end of the line which spots the divergence on the indicator.